# Wrapping an image over a product image convexly

Tags: imagemagick

**What I want**: When I apply an image over the pillow texture the artwork of the image should wrap convexly on the pillow.

[Here is the link for the desired image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGCAe.png)

Above output is the correct output that I want

**Note**: In the above image, you can see the image is wrapped around the corners and convex from the center.

Problem: But when I apply image over the pillow texture image artwork is not curved convexly.

[Here is the the output I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luCTx.png)

Also, for reference,

[here is the product image that I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NXBx.jpg)

[And here is the artwork, that I am overlaying it with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d51kt.jpg)

Also, in the product image linked above, as you can see, there is some distortion in the top left corner, if I am overlaying it with any design, how can I achieve that distortion as well.

I am new to imagemagick, so are there any good resources to learn from and practice with?

Comment: Hey, welcome to stack overflow! Please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/tour to understand how questions are asked and what purpose they serve on here. 
Product or service recommendations or comparisons are not something, you should ask for on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do that in ImageMagick.

Input:

[image]

First make a mask for the pillow. ImageMagick could not get a good mask, so I used http://remove.bg to make the background transparent and then extracted the alpha channel and got this:

[image]

I then measured the size and offset of the white part of the mask:

```
convert mask.png -format "%@" info:
642x646+78+77
```

Then I processed the images. I resized the text image, then applied pincushion distortion (opposite of barrel distortion) and inserted it into a white image the size of the pillow at the offset location from above. Then using the mask, I did a blend composite of the pillow and distorted image to make the result. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#barrel

```
convert pillow.jpg \
\( -size 800x800 xc:white \
\( pillow_overlay.jpg -resize 646x646 -distort barrel "0.0 0.0 -0.2 1.3" \) \
-geometry +78+77 -compose over -composite +geometry \) \
mask.png -define compose:args=60,40 -compose blend -composite \
pillow_new.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: sorry for replying so late, thank you, it worked for me.